Tikz plot with varying line color/intensity
Is it possible to use \draw plot and somehow vary the color on a step-by-step basis? Consider
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (100bp);
\draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(99.8109bp,-6.1469bp) (49.9865bp,-38.7829bp) (-24.8918bp,-42.9607bp) (-86.7667bp,-16.4459bp)};
\draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(89.7481bp,44.1052bp) (62.4466bp,3.7106bp) (-0.1181bp,-10.6292bp) (-61.9605bp,5.4711bp) (-87.4642bp,46.9736bp)};
\draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(85.9434bp,51.1246bp) (63.6401bp,9.0499bp) (3.6433bp,-8.2952bp) (-58.9736bp,4.5745bp) (-88.0193bp,43.6533bp)};
\draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(59.0332bp,-17.6081bp) (-11.7676bp,-29.9046bp) (-76.7635bp,-10.4096bp)};
\draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(96.2445bp,-27.1474bp) (40.7987bp,-56.7124bp) (-35.2702bp,-58.7945bp) (-92.9990bp,-33.5590bp)};
\draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(82.9428bp,-55.8614bp) (23.1728bp,-75.5383bp) (-46.2282bp,-71.4894bp)};
\draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(89.0722bp,-45.4548bp) (30.0434bp,-67.8957bp) (-42.5929bp,-64.7659bp)};
\draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(52.6756bp,-32.7719bp) (-21.3784bp,-38.3862bp) (-83.9105bp,-12.8575bp)};
\end{tikzpicture}

This creates a circle with several smooth curves plotted inside the circle using the default line settings.
What I'd like to do is provide line intensity (or color) at each coordinate value. Thus, a curve might start out at 25% black, rise in intensity over a few steps to 100% black, stay at 100% for a while, then fade to 0% black over some further steps.
Understanding what this figure is supposed to represent may help to visualize the intent. The paths shown are the moon as it moves through the sky (the paths are several days apart). When the sun is above the horizon, then the moon is somewhat visible, depending on how near the sun is to the moon. I'd like to fade these curves based on the proximity of the sun. If the sun is "far away" or below the horizon, then the moon is fully visible, but when the sun rises, then the degree of visibility of the moon is reduced (and the line should be lighter) depending on the proximity of the sun.
Is there a way to specify the color of each portion of a path as the coordinates that specify the path are given?

Please post a proper MWE. Not only is your code missing a preamble and the document environment, it also ends a center without beginning it.

The backends of TikZ only allow one color per path. You can shade it but that doesn't change the color in relation to the path travelled but over the area it covers. You can split up each plot in its separate segments (a Bézier curve) via a decoration and draw each curve with a different color. With the spath3 library we could split it up in segments of a specific length and draw these with a different color, though. Do you have a reference how this should look? I do have troubles seeing sun and moon and where which colors should be.

@Qrrbrbirlbel thanks. Easiest is probably to represent these paths in piece-wise linear form. If the pieces are short enough, it will appear smooth.

@RandallFairman Look, the helper is usually not god-like and can answer everything on the spot. As asked in the very first comment: please create a runable MWE so that the helper can work on it and try it out.
